# How to move my party from one location to another?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, gm-techniques

I am currently DMing a campaign in a world I have built from the outside-in over a four month period. I have spent a lot of time on the grand scheme rather than the minor details, and after the first two sessions I have realized that the area in which I started the PCs is not as fun or rewarding as I had hoped for 1st–2nd level characters.

I would like to smoothly transition my party from one area of the world to another by using some sort of story-driven motivation. I have brain stormed a few ideas but thought I would come to some of the experts for help!

The party began as slaves with no recollection of their past, so there is an open story to be brought to life there. Excited to hear from you all, thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I suggest you take the [Tour]—we may be a little different from what you are used to. The format of the site is hyper-focused on answering specific questions authoritatively; this focus has left is rather poor at discussion and idea generation, and as such we do not host those things here. We would be happy to flesh out any ideas you come up with, to answer any questions about the details, but for actually hashing out an idea, you need a discussion forum. Luckily, we do [recommend several of those](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/4563).

Comment: You might also find some help with idea generation in [chat]--I've always found the people there very helpful when brainstorming. You'll need 20 reputation to talk in chat, so here's an upvote to get you a quarter of the way there =)

Comment: Are you looking for ideas, or looking for methods? We can help with methods—in fact, that question would already have answers in [How do I quickly get the PCs to a distant location for the next adventure?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63207) —but for idea-generation the site's non-discussion Q&A voting system is poorly suited (as KRyan aptly explains).

Comment: @nitsua60 You’ll note that chat is the most-recommended discussion forum in the list I linked ;) Unfortunately, Caelan does not quite have enough rep for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I quickly get the PCs to a distant location for the next adventure?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63207/how-do-i-quickly-get-the-pcs-to-a-distant-location-for-the-next-adventure)

Comment: @KRyan I had remembered that chat's on the list, but I usually like to separately call it out anyway for a few reasons. (1) For some who may think "ugh, I just created an account here, I don't want to go create an account somewhere else" I like to point out a chat-space where they won't need a new account; (2) I hope sometimes that the sort of comment I left will lead to a few "let's get them into chat" upvotes. I don't know how anybody else feels about that sort of upvote, but I like tossing them out there.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help guys. Read over http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63207/how-do-i-quickly-get-the-pcs-to-a-distant-location-for-the-next-adventure and am now going to go check out RPG chat.

Comment: @nitsua60 chatvote added